# Getting error Symbol current_process multiply defined, confused on what error means and how to fix?

Tags: c, keil

I'm just trying to get my code to compile, but I keep running into errors:

```
.\Objects\Lab4.axf: Error: L6200E: Symbol current_process multiply defined (by lab4_t0.o and 3140_concur.o).
.\Objects\Lab4.axf: Error: L6200E: Symbol current_process multiply defined (by process.o and 3140_concur.o).
.\Objects\Lab4.axf: Error: L6200E: Symbol process_queue multiply defined (by lab4_t0.o and 3140_concur.o).
.\Objects\Lab4.axf: Error: L6200E: Symbol process_queue multiply defined (by process.o and 3140_concur.o).
```

I really don't understand the error message.

First, I'm not sure if `process.o` is referring to `process.h` or `process.c` (so I don't know which file to focus on). Same goes for `3140_concur.o` which has `3140_concur.c` and `3140_concur.h`.

Secondly, I'm not sure what "multiply defined" means. I figure that means I instantiate `current_process` & `process_queue` twice, but honestly I can't see how because I only "define" `current_process` and `process_queue` in `process.h`:

```
process_t * current_process; 
process_t * process_queue;
```

I don't even see how `lab4_t0.c` could be defining `process_queue` either so I'm confused by why these "multiply defined" error messages are popping up.

ALTHOUGH, I have a feeling its because in`3140_concur.h` I `#include "process.h"` AND in `process.h` I define `process_queue` and `current_process` AND I also `#include "3140_concur.h"`. Same goes for `lab4_t0.c` (I `#include "process.h"`). But the reason I do that is b/c `process.c` uses methods from `3140_concur.h` and also `lab4_t0.c` uses methods from from `process.h`.

So if my hunch is correct, and that's the reason I'm getting the errors, how can I properly modularize my code (aka what should I `#include` and not `#include`) so that I don't get these errors?

If someone could type the code I need to do to remove these errors that would be great!

Note: If you were wondering why I created `process.h` and why I didn't just put everything in `process.h` in `3140_concur.h` file, the reason for that is that it caused errors w/ `lock.c` that I don't want to go into here.

### Brief summary of my code

**lock.c**

```
#include "lock.h"
extern process_t * current_process; 
extern process_t * process_queue;
```

**lock.h**

```
#ifndef __LOCK_H_INCLUDED__
#define __LOCK_H_INCLUDED__
#include "3140_concur.h"
#include "shared_structs.h"
void l_init(lock_t* l);
void l_lock(lock_t* l);
void l_unlock(lock_t* l);
#endif /* __LOCK_H_INCLUDED */
```

**3140_concur.c**

```
#include "3140_concur.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
```

**3140_concur.h**

```
#ifndef __3140_CONCUR_H__
#define __3140_CONCUR_H__

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fsl_device_registers.h>
#include "process.h"

void process_blocked (void);

void process_terminated (void);

unsigned int * process_stack_init (void (*f)(void), int n);

void process_stack_free (unsigned int *sp, int n);

void process_begin (void);

#endif
```

**process.h**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fsl_device_registers.h>
#include "3140_concur.h"

struct process_state;
typedef struct process_state process_t;

unsigned int * process_select (unsigned int * cursp);

process_t * current_process; 
process_t * process_queue;

void process_start (void);

int process_create (void (*f)(void), int n);
```

**process.c**

(I do `process_t* process_queue = NULL; & process_t* current_process = NULL;` b/c I want them to be NULL before any functions are called)

```
#include "3140_concur.h" 
#include "shared_structs.h"
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <fsl_device_registers.h>

process_t* process_queue = NULL;
process_t* current_process = NULL;
```

**lab4_t0.c**

```
#include "process.h"
#include "utils.h"
#include "lock.h"

lock_t l;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: See the second section of my answer to [How do I use `extern` to share variables between source files in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/)  — that part titled 'Not so good way to define global variables'. You should use `extern` before the variable names in `process.h`.  If more than one source file includes `process.h`, a compiler is within its rights to complain about multiple definition, though on many systems you'll get away with it.  (If only one file includes `process.h`, why do you have the header?)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Oh well that fixed my "multiply defined" error but now I'm back to my original error (which is why I created `process.h` in the first place):

Comment: `.\Objects\Lab4.axf: Error: L6218E: Undefined symbol l_init (referred from lab4_t0.o).`

Comment: `.\Objects\Lab4.axf: Error: L6218E: Undefined symbol l_lock (referred from lab4_t0.o).`

Comment: `.\Objects\Lab4.axf: Error: L6218E: Undefined symbol l_unlock (referred from lab4_t0.o).`

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Do you know why I'm getting these errors?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Tbh I don't know why I have `process.h`. It was just something I was told would fix the errors ` Undefined symbol l_init`, etc, but clearly it has not

Comment: On the face of it, the `l_init()`, `l_lock()` and `l_unlock()` undefined errors are because you aren't linking `lock.o` into the executable, or you haven't yet created `lock.c` (so you aren't linking it), or you have not defined the functions in `lock.c` even though the file exists, or the functions defined in another file that you aren't linking, or … The functions you try to call are not defined in the object files (or libraries) that you're trying to link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `extern` to my defintion of `current_process` and `process_queue` in `process.h` removed my "multiply defined" errors (thanks to @JonathanLeffler)

Now I'm getting a different error, but at least I resolved this one :)